# Click element up the dom with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu and I want an element with a class of active, parent element's sibling element to be clicked automatically on page load.

Here is my HTML:

```
<li class="level1">
  <span class="level1 drop-down clicked"><a href="#" class="level1">Oranges</a></span>
  <ul class="level2" style="display: block;">
    <li class="level2"><a href="#" class="level1">Peel</a></li>
    <li class="level2"><a href="#" class="level1">Pips</a></li>
    <li class="level2 active"><a href="#" class="level1">Pegs</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I've tried

`jQuery('li.level2.active').parent('li.level1').children('span.level1.drop-down').click();`

but it does not work.  I'm not sure if I'm using the parent & children method's properly.

Although, `jQuery("span.drop-down.level1").click();` does work, but it selects all the elements with that class which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Look at your `jQuery('li.level2.active')` that should be level12, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `li.level1` is two steps up, you need `.parents()`, which selects up multiple levels, instead of `.parent()`, which is only one.

```
jQuery('li.level2.active').parents('li.level1').children('span.level1.drop-down').click();
                                ^^^^
```

Comment: Interesting. I've always gone with .closest(). I've used .parent() before but never heard of .parents()

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery('li.active').closest('li.level1').find('span.level1.drop-down').trigger('click');
```